# MYSQL sum() returning double score

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following query to produce a leaderboard, but for some reason it's returning the score as double the value.

```
SELECT p.user_id, u.first, SUM(points) AS score FROM points AS p LEFT 
JOIN users AS u ON p.user_id = u.fb_id WHERE p.action_time > 
'1492732800' GROUP BY p.user_id ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10
```

What might be causing this to happen?

Thanks

Comment: Can you also provide some sample data so that we are able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: You probably have multiple records for a user id on one table or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to aggregate the points in a separate subquery and join to that:

```
SELECT t1.fb_id, t1.first, t2.score
FROM users t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user_id, SUM(points) AS score
    FROM points
    WHERE action_time > '1492732800'
    GROUP BY user_id
) t2
    ON t2.user_id = t1.fb_id
```